# Creating a Widget area in my Wordpress Timber Theme

Tags: wordpress, twig, theming

I am using Timber to create a very basic Wordpress theme.

I'm stuck though.

I want to create Widget areas in the theme and I can't figure it out.

I've tried following the instructions, for creating a Dynamic Widget, on this page - https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/Sidebar#method-3-dynamic

By following this I've added the following code to my files -
To page-frontpage.php I added

```
$context['dynamic_sidebar'] = Timber::get_widgets('dynamic_sidebar');
```

so it now looks like this:

```
<?php

$context = Timber::get_context();
$post = new TimberPost();
$context['post'] = $post;
$context['dynamic_sidebar'] = Timber::get_widgets('dynamic_sidebar');
Timber::render(array('page-' . $post->post_name . '.twig', 'page.twig'), $context);
```

I then added this to the base.twig file

```
<section>
    {{ dynamic_sidebar }}
</section>
```

I expected to see a new Widget area in the Wordpress Admin under Appearance -> Customize but got nothing.

I've struggled with this for the past few hours and made little progress, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've fixed this issue.

I just had to go back to basics and create the widgets in the functions.php file, so now my code looks something like this.

in functions.php

```
register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => 'Home left sidebar',
            'id' => 'home_left',
            'before_widget' => '<div>',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
        ) );
```

in page-home.php

```
$context['home_left'] = Timber::get_widgets('home_left');
```

in home.twig

```
<div class="left-box">{{ home_left }}</div>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: couldn't thank any more, you saved me a couple of hours..